# "Move the Camera" in OpenGL - Cant seem to make projection matrices work correctly?

Tags: c#, opengl

I have been dabbling in OpenGL for a while now, i spent some time working on it in c++ but I moved on to trying it in C#, which i=I'm far more comfortable with, using the OpenTK Wrapper.

I have been able to draw a simple wire-frame cube to the screen but now I am trying to implement a "movable camera" I'm finding it very difficult.
I have attempted to translate the OpenGL red book's example code to C# but it doesn't seem to work, same for any examples i find online i cant seem to adapt their code to work with mine.

Here's my code, I've commented on pretty much every line as I am finding it easier to learn while I document it.

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Shifted
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double Offset = 0;
        public static Vector3 m_eye;
        public static Vector3 m_target;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (GameWindow window = new GameWindow())
            {
                window.Load += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    //Vertical Sync on or off
                    window.VSync = VSyncMode.On;
                    //Set window title
                    window.Title = "Test";
                    //set the "clear color", the colour displayed when nothing is drawn and were looking to infinity
                    GL.ClearColor(Color4.Black);
                    //Set the viewport to match the screen width/height
                    GL.Viewport(0, 0, window.Width, window.Height);

                    m_eye = new Vector3(0, 0, 10f);
                    m_target = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                };

                window.Resize += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    //on window resize, resize the viewport. (the "window" were looking into the OpenGL "world" with)
                    GL.Viewport(0, 0, window.Width, window.Height);
                };

                //heres where all game logic should be stored
                window.UpdateFrame += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Offset += e.Time;
                    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.W))
                    {
                        m_eye = m_eye + new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);
                        m_target = m_target + new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);
                    }
                    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
                    {
                        m_eye = m_eye - new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);
                        m_target = m_target - new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(m_eye);
                };

                //heres where everything that draws should go
                window.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>
                {

                    //Clear the buffer to draw a fresh image
                    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
                    //Set draw mode to lines (wiremesh)
                    GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Line);
                    //Sets up the projection matrix. Projection = 2d, modelview = 3d to my belief. Maybe i just dont get this state machine stuff...
                    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
                    GL.LoadIdentity();
                    //set the size of the the camera projection, basically clipping planes
                    GL.Ortho(0.0f, window.Width, 0.0f, window.Height, 0.0f, 1000.0f);

                    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
                    GL.LoadIdentity();
                    Matrix4 modelview = Matrix4.LookAt(m_eye, m_target, Vector3.UnitY);
                    GL.LoadMatrix(ref modelview);

                    //Set what colour to draw in
                    GL.Color3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                    //8 Vertices for a cube, shouldnt have to redefine this every frame but it'll do for testing.
                    double[] vertices = new double[]{100,100,0,
                                                     100,200,0,
                                                     200,200,0,
                                                     200,100,0,
                                                     200+(Math.Sin(Offset)*10),100+(Math.Cos(Offset)*10),-100,
                                                     200+(Math.Sin(Offset)*10),200+(Math.Cos(Offset)*10),-100,
                                                     100+(Math.Sin(Offset)*10),200+(Math.Cos(Offset)*10),-100,
                                                     100+(Math.Sin(Offset)*10),100+(Math.Cos(Offset)*10),-100};
                    //Indice order to draw the cube in, same as last comment.
                    byte[] indices = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 7, 7, 6, 1, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7 };
                    //Enable the use of vertex arrays
                    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
                    //Tell it where to find the vertices
                    GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Double, 0, vertices);
                    //Draw them
                    GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedByte, indices);
                    //Flush it to the buffer
                    GL.Flush();
                    //swap the back buffer we're drawing to to be the front buffer thats displayed
                    window.SwapBuffers();
                };
                //Run at X frames per second. Null = 60 FPS, 200 = no cap, anything in between = that cap.
                window.Run(200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i press W and S, it does not "move the camera" relative to the cube as id expect, instead the cube doesnt appear to move at all, and it just begins to clip from either the front or rear plane until its completely out of view, depending on the key you hold. The values appear to reflect the `GL.Ortho`values but the cube is not moved relative to the camera, it just starts clipping while in view?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The z coordinates of your "rotating cube backplane" is behind the camera. Is it on purpose ?

Comment: Yes i quickly realised this, ive been screwing around with the values and realised what i had done. I now have it so the m_eye is at `Vector3(0f, 0f, 10f);` and its target point is `Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);`, so it should be looking at objects where Z < 10 yes? I still cannot see it.

Comment: Toying with your code, I just changed m_eye to new Vector3(0f, 0f, 10f); and it works.

Comment: Yeah that "works", but as soon as you go to move the camera it screws up again.. i think i must be doing something really wrong. Ill update my main post to reflect my code changes.

Comment: In orthographic projection, z distance doesn't affect object size, that is, objects farther from the camera do not appear smaller than close ones. I guess you expect to see some kind of perspective projection. Take a look at glFrustum (and prepare for some headaches). Do not loose faith thoug; matrix math is the steep part of 3D learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see, what you've been doing was keeping the cube in 0,0,0. The way 3d games work is the world moves around the player. So before you draw the cube do `glTranslatef(m_eye.x * -1, m_eye.y * -1, m_eye.z * -1)`

EDIT: if you do this, your whole sign and cosign setup in your vertex creation shouldn't be need, therefore you don't need to make it every update.

EDIT EDIT: Use `Glu.Perspective(45, width / height, 0.1, 100);`

Comment: The sin/cos was just to add a bit of perspective to the drawing when t he camera was looking at it face on, so i knew i was actually drawing a cube not some horrible square monstrosity, but without moving the camera i obviously couldnt see the back - so instead i made the back move. - the vertexs on the cube are intended to move just so i get abit of additional visual feedback from my tests.

Comment: I changed the code to `GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Double, 0, vertices);
                    //Draw them
                    GL.Translate(m_eye.X * -1, m_eye.Y * -1, m_eye.Z * -1);
                    GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedByte, indices);
                    //Flush it to the buffer
                    GL.Flush();` and it still doesnt work, though that does make more sense than what i originally had.

Comment: So what does it look like now?

Comment: does it still not move or does the cube become distorted? or what? is it just a white square?

Comment: The exact same as it did before. No movement relative to the "camera"

Comment: how exactly is there no relative movement? does it look like a square and not a cube or what?

Comment: yep, so what you are doing is intialiazing an orthographics view (GL.Ortho) you need to initialize a perspective view (GL.Perspective i think), perspective view is the same as real life. Ortho is sort of like having 2D in a 3D space. Good link for this stuff: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/opengl_projections.html

Comment: It's still a cube with the rear plane moving in a circular motion, as it is if i do not have any of the code between `GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);` & `GL.LoadMatrix(ref modelview);`. When i press W or S i can see that the Vector3 of m_eye moves like it should, but the cube stays in the exact same position constantly completely independent of how i position m_eye, whereas i want it to move as if i were using a camera. When Z of m_eye > 1000 the rear plane of the cube starts become clipped as if it were leaving the ortho area, same as the front plane clips when Z of m_eye < 0.

Comment: In other words it doesn't appear that adding `GL.Translate(m_eye.X * -1, m_eye.Y * -1, m_eye.Z * -1);` is affecting the position of the Cube at all, i assume its not in the right state to accept that function when I'm calling it?

Comment: yes, it looks like there is no movement because ortho doesn't acount for depth perspective like perspective which is what you need. And the glTranslate effects rending nothing else so it will render in the right pos even if it isn't.

Comment: Right that makes sense, ive changed ortho to frustrum but now i have nothing drawn at all, just a plain black screen..

Comment: Yeah, know what you mean, when I first learnt opengl I made the same mistakes just like all of you. Id recommend thebennybox really good tuts.

Comment: you need a perspective view, what frustum does is render onoly what is in a defined space, so not your cube in this case.

Comment: this is what you should need: `Glu.Perspective(45, width / height, 0.1, 100);` the 45 is FOV. width/height is the aspect ration then followed by zNear and zFar